# Trigger to delete column only if all values are null

Tags: sql-server, triggers

How can I create a Trigger that delete a column only if all values on a specific field are null?

Comment: That's great but what have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by 'delete a column'?

Comment: A field normaly has only one value. So specify your question.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't want rows inserted into a table with all values as `NULL`?

Comment: When I drop the column AGE in the table PERSON, the trigger watch if every row in PERSON have AGE NULL, for all the rows. If at least a row in the field AGE is diferrent to null, can't alter the table

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "create a trigger"?  Do you mean that you want an update/delete trigger that would delete the column at the point when all the values become `NULL`?

If so, that is not possible.  "Deleting a column" is really `alter table drop column`.  In the Remarks section for the `create trigger` [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799%28v=sql.110%29.aspx):

> Additionally, the following Transact-SQL statements are not allowed
>   inside the body of a DML trigger when it is used against the table or
>   view that is the target of the triggering action . . .
>
> - ALTER TABLE when used to do the following: Add, modify, or drop    columns. Switch partitions. Add or drop PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE
>     constraints.

Hence what you want to do is not possible.  Further, I don't understand why you would want to do it.  A data-driven change to the data structure seems strange.  I am guessing that your data structure really wants to be a junction/association table, but you don't provide enough information to speculate further.